# Can I create games using XNA if I have Visual Studio 2010 installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna

Pretty straight forward question. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be a pedant, yes you can: just not inside of VS 2010. You can install a 2008 Express version side-by-side and use that, until they update XNA for 2010.

Answer (score 5):

Basically: XNA Game Studios 3.0 and 3.1 go with Visual Studio 2008. (Note: anywhere I say "Visual Studio" it also applies to Visual C# Express.)

XNA Game Studio 4.0 (currently in beta) goes with Visual Studio 2010. (Note: XNA GS 4.0 is part of Windows Phone Developer Tools).

Both Visual Studio and XNA Game Studio (and the XNA runtimes, for that matter) can be installed side-by-side with older/newer versions of the same.

XNA Game Studio (which basically means the content pipeline, push to Xbox, project wizards, etc) will only integrate with the associated version of Visual Studio.

Of course you can *reference* any version of the XNA assemblies from any version of Visual Studio. But without the content pipeline it can be a bit limiting.

Answer (score 2):

XNA GS 3.0 won't work inside of VS 2010. There is no .net 4.0 version yet

Answer (score 0):

No , Currently Visual Studio 2010 does not support XNA . But you have a option of installing XNA Game Studio 4.0 CTP .

But i think it is for Windows Phone 7 .

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. Will be supported in the future.