# How to access XNA 3.1 Templates in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna

I have installed `XNA Game Studio 3.1`, but I can't see the `Game Template` in `Visual Studio 2010` on `Windows server 2008`.

There is no driver for graphics and `XNA 4.0` won't install, could it be related?

How do I solve my problem?

Comment: Which version of XNA 4.0 are you trying to install? The stand-alone package, or the one bundled with the phone development kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XNA Game Studio **3.1** works with Visual C# Express **2008** and Visual Studio **2008**.

XNA Game Studio **4.0** works with Visual C# Express **2010** and Visual Studio **2010**.

There is no way around this. I explain this in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261682/can-i-create-games-using-xna-if-i-have-visual-studio-2010-installed/3264020#3264020).

If you want to use XNA 3.1, you will need to install Visual Studio 2008 (or C# Express 2008). All of these things install side-by-side - you can have both 2008 and 2010 installed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

did yiu install vs first?

In situation ssuch as thi sits often best to start uninstalling all the xna components restart and try again.

are you sure you restarted vs after installing xna?

I have not had problems with xna (but then i am not running server 2008 and i have graphics drivers).

I dont see why a lack of drivers would stop the template from being visible though.

Comment: lack of template is in VS 2010 which i installed earlier than XNA.

Comment: Lack of drivers is stopping XNA 4.0 to get installed which I can access through VS 2010.

Comment: XNA 3.1 though installed VS 2008, a bit of it, but it also is not showing any template. Re-installing VS is out of question, I won't do that for any reason other that OS crash or OS re-install. Thanks Anyway.